# What is the purpose of using the paramater "const [variable_type] &" if it creates a local copy?

Tags: c++

I read that doing something like

```
void print_in_reverse (const std::string & str)
{
     std::string::const_iterator beg(str.cbegin()), it(str.cend());
     if (it != beg)
         while (--it != beg) std::cout << *it;
}
```

will create a local copy of the string passed in. So what is the point of the above? It is not any more computationally efficient than doing the layman's version,

```
void print_in_reverse (std::string str)
{
     std::string::const_iterator beg(str.cbegin()), it(str.cend());
     if (it != beg)
         while (--it != beg) std::cout << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If that's what you read, then it's wrong. Passing by reference is exactly how to avoid creating a local copy.

However, in some cases, passing an argument of the wrong type forces the creation of a temporary with the right type. For example:

```
print_in_reverse("abc");
```

creates a temporary `std::string` from the string literal, since that's the type that the function needs.

Comment: I know that passing a reference is the way to avoid a local copy, but I remember reading in C++ Primer that passing a const reference will somethings create a local copy

Comment: Do you have the exact quote?

Comment: @DonaldKnuthLied: Presumably, it says that passing a different type causes the creation of a temporary (in the calling function - not local to the called function), as I described.